# What is the difference between fallback, mirror and cache directory

Tags: directory

I don't understand the difference of meaning between directory fallback, directory mirror,and cache.

Please, explain the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit more simple than the question itself:

- **Fallback** equals to "when an original is not available, use replica"
- **Mirror** is just a network-served full cache, *signed by an original*
- **Cache** is a very *local* cache, that's it